# SQL statement for TOP 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to write a SELECT Statement that will SELECT the top 3 rows from the table tblProducts WHERE the Vender ID is like the first two characters of the entered data.  I decide to use the IN operation but isn't not working.   I have also tried LIKE instead on the IN, but I keeping getting error message with this line.  Is my logic wrong?

```
SELECT TOP 3
FROM tblProducts
WHERE VendorID IN UCase(Me.txtProdID.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing your column definitions after `top 3`.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM tblProducts
WHERE VendorID = UCase(Me.txtProdID.Text)
```

Also if you want to use `IN`, I think you need parentheses.  I changed it to `=`.

---

Edit, after rereading `WHERE the Vender ID is like the first two characters of the entered data.`
You would want to use `LIKE` with `LEFT` (or `SUBSTRING`), not `IN` for your `WHERE` criteria:

```
WHERE VendorID like Left(UCase(Me.txtProdID.Text),2) + '%'
```

Also, you may not need `ucase` -- depends on your database collation.

Answer (score 0):

try using parenthesis, also that .text might cause issues, add .toString(), or since its an ID, maybe toInt()

```
SELECT TOP (3)
FROM tblProducts
WHERE VendorID like UCase(Me.txtProdID.Text.toInt())
```

Comment: I'm not sure which platform this code would ever compile on.

Comment: I was under the impression that he was getting the values from a textbox, but I have not enough reputation to put a comment to ask him to be specific :/ Im assuming maybe he missed a parse from textbox value to something else (int or string)